# Lots of IPs with MAC 00:00:00:00:00:00 . What are the possible causes?

Tags: arp

On my enterprise we have some times this **ARP output** (read on a computer with Linux):

```
$ cat /proc/net/arp
192.168.0.176    0x1         0x0         00:00:00:00:00:00     *        eth0
192.168.0.93     0x1         0x0         00:00:00:00:00:00     *        eth0    192.168.0.112    0x1         0x0         00:00:00:00:00:00     *        eth0    192.168.0.169    0x1         0x0         00:00:00:00:00:00     *        eth0
192.168.0.252    0x1         0x0         00:00:00:00:00:00     *        eth0
192.168.0.188    0x1         0x0         00:00:00:00:00:00     *        eth0
192.168.0.245    0x1         0x0         00:00:00:00:00:00     *        eth0
192.168.0.162    0x1         0x0         00:00:00:00:00:00     *        eth0    192.168.0.181    0x1         0x0         00:00:00:00:00:00     *        eth0    192.168.0.238    0x1         0x0         00:00:00:00:00:00     *        eth0    192.168.0.193    0x1         0x0         00:00:00:00:00:00     *        eth0
192.168.0.129    0x1         0x0         00:00:00:00:00:00     *        eth0
192.168.0.1      0x1         0x2         78:94:b4:82:5c:e0     *        eth0
192.168.0.186    0x1         0x0         00:00:00:00:00:00     *        eth0    192.168.0.103    0x1         0x0         00:00:00:00:00:00     *        eth0
192.168.0.205    0x1         0x0         00:00:00:00:00:00     *        eth0
192.168.0.77     0x1         0x0         00:00:00:00:00:00     *        eth0
192.168.0.160    0x1         0x0         00:00:00:00:00:00     *        eth0
192.168.0.243    0x1         0x0         00:00:00:00:00:00     *        eth0
192.168.0.32     0x1         0x0         00:00:00:00:00:00     *        eth0
192.168.0.89     0x1         0x0         00:00:00:00:00:00     *        eth0
192.168.0.108    0x1         0x0         00:00:00:00:00:00     *        eth0
192.168.0.146    0x1         0x0         00:00:00:00:00:00     *        eth0
192.168.0.248    0x1         0x0         00:00:00:00:00:00     *        eth0
192.168.0.184    0x1         0x0         00:00:00:00:00:00     *        eth0
192.168.0.18     0x1         0x0         00:00:00:00:00:00     *        eth0
192.168.0.241    0x1         0x0         00:00:00:00:00:00     *        eth0
192.168.0.253    0x1         0x0         00:00:00:00:00:00     *        eth0
192.168.0.189    0x1         0x0         00:00:00:00:00:00     *        eth0
192.168.0.163    0x1         0x0         00:00:00:00:00:00     *        eth0
192.168.0.246    0x1         0x0         00:00:00:00:00:00     *        eth0
192.168.0.182    0x1         0x0         00:00:00:00:00:00     *        eth0
192.168.0.156    0x1         0x0         00:00:00:00:00:00     *        eth0
192.168.0.239    0x1         0x0         00:00:00:00:00:00     *        eth0
192.168.0.73     0x1         0x0         00:00:00:00:00:00     *        eth0
```

The main **DHCP Server** is a **Vodafone H500** router that gives nearly no information and has no remote console, so I had to read this **ARP table** from a DHCP cliente computer.

To note: all MACs are `00:00:00:00:00:00` except the one from the router (for auditing, I have only this computer connected via RJ45 cable).

What is the **possible origin** of such strange behavior in a network?
Maybe some ARP Flood?

**Further data**:

- In my case, the device with strange behavior is a OpenWRT v18 system (Mikrotik RouterBoard RB951Ui-2HnD), and range 192.168.0.x/24 is the WAN side. This behavior is not happening on two other devices running OpenWRT v18 too (on different networks).

Comment: What do you see on other computers connected to this network if you were to run the same command?   Have you tried to ping any of the addresses directly to see if the ARP table gets updated afterward?   I know on some of our switches the MAC address wont update in the arp list until you ping them directly.   After pinging the IP address directly, then I can see the MAC address associated with the IP.

Comment: @Richie086 : Other computer on the same LAN only show really existing devices (IPs). If I ping sweep (most of) the network range (2-250), the ARP table shows all the pinged IPs as `00:00:00:00:00:00`, but after a few seconds all that "ghost" IPs disappear, and they only remain the real devices (none of them with `00:00:00:00:00:00` ). However, on this dirty device the ghost devices remain.

Comment: @Richie086 : Tested direct ping, but no changes on ARP table.

Comment: Added further data: this test is being performed on a OpenWRT router.

Comment: Might want to run a packet capture with wire shark to determine what the origin of the traffic is.  I would limit the capture filter to only show traffic on your 192.168.0.0 network.  Let me know if you need help setting that up.

Comment: Yes, @Richie086 . Some help with such command-line for nMap would be fine.

Comment: the reason I suggest Wireshark is it will give you a better idea of what is causing these phantom IP addresses to appear.   Am I understanding correctly when you say "(for auditing, I have only this computer connected via RJ45 cable)." that this network consists of your machine and the router, no other machines?   if that is the case, you are definitely going to need to do a packet capture to figure out what the hell is going on.  Just a guess, is the router doing any DHCP snooping?   It's usually an option in the dhcp server settings.

Comment: Also if you could do a Nmap scan on your router from your workstation.   I'd do nmap -vv -A 192.168.0.1 and post the results in your original question so I can take a quick look I would appreciate it!   -vv just means be very verbose with the output, and -A tells nmap to load all of it's modules and scripts for the scan on 192.168.0.1.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109131/discussion-between-richie086-and-sopalajo-de-arrierez).